# In Pycharm can not add conda environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I hava dowmload and installer Anaconda3 successfully ，but when I add conda environment  in pycharm ,has the  error "D:\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'create': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

how to  deal with this problem

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide path to the conda executable for making a conda venv and not python. See the image attached below to see a possible location of the conda executable.

PS: I don't have 10 point yet so the image is a link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsSw3.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved.

Execute the following  command in dos

```
Conda  create -p D:\condaevn\pyleran -y python=3.7
```

to creat a conda evn

[image]

then in the Pycharm, choose the "Existiing environment" and use the evn created by dos command

[image]

Comment: Is specifying the location even necessary?